# How can I display multiple.xpt files in R shiny and filter them based on their columns?

Tags: r, shiny

When I try to upload multiple .xpt files to show the tables in the main panel of the R shiny app, it gives me the following issue.

I am also looking at the filtering option. I would like to filter by columns while uploading multiple files so that the appropriate rows in the main panel of each data frame/datatable are displayed.

**Error:**
`Warning: Error in This kind of input is not handled`

Can Someone help me for the solution?

**code:**

```
library(shiny)
library(haven)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File", multiple = TRUE,
                accept = c(
                  "text/csv",
                  "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                  ".csv", ".xpt")
      ),
      tags$hr(),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("contents")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  # output$contents <- renderTable({
  #   # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
  #   # and uploads a file, it will be a data frame with 'name',
  #   # 'size', 'type', and 'datapath' columns. The 'datapath'
  #   # column will contain the local filenames where the data can
  #   # be found.
  #   inFile <- input$file1
  #   
  #   if (is.null(inFile))
  #     return(NULL)
  #   
  #   read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header)
  # })
  
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    # input$file1 will be NULL initially. After the user selects
    # and uploads a file, it will be a data frame with 'name',
    # 'size', 'type', and 'datapath' columns. The 'datapath'
    # column will contain the local filenames where the data can
    # be found.
    inFile <- input$file1
    
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    
    read_xpt(inFile$datapath) 
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Xpt1:**

```
STUDYID   DOMAIN    CR_VALUE
1           CR        1.5
2           CR        1.5
3           CR        1.5
```

**Xpt2:**

```
STUDYID   DOMAIN    CM_VALUE
1           CM        1.5
2           CM        1.8
3           CR        1.9
```

**After filtering with the value 1.9, this is the expected output.**

```
3           CR        1.9
```

Comment: Please share the output(s) of `dput(read_xpt("datapath_to_your_example_xpt_files"))` to make this question reproducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the app starts to fail when multiple files are uploaded, is because `inFile$datapath` stops being a single value. Now it contains multiple datapaths corresponding to each file.

Here is an example app that lets the user upload multiple .xpt files and select which file to display on the table.

```
library(shiny)
library(haven)
library(stringr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
        multiple = TRUE,
        accept = c(
          "text/csv",
          "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
          ".csv", ".xpt"
        )
      ),
      tags$hr(),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
      uiOutput("files_available")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("contents")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$files_available <- renderUI({
    req(input$file1)
    selectInput("name", str_to_title("select which file to show"), choices = input$file1$name)
  })

  df <- reactive({
    req(input$name)
    read_xpt(input$file1$datapath[[which(input$file1$name == input$name)]])
  })

  output$contents <- renderTable({
    df()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Edit: The app with filter:

```
library(shiny)
library(haven)
library(stringr)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
        multiple = TRUE,
        accept = c(
          "text/csv",
          "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
          ".csv", ".xpt"
        )
      ),
      tags$hr(),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
      uiOutput("files_available"),
      uiOutput("filters")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("tables")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  nms <- reactiveVal(NULL)

  suffixes <- c("STUDYID", "DOMAIN", "VALUE")

  df <- reactive({
    req(input$file1)
    input$file1$datapath %>%
      map(~ read_xpt(.x))
  })

  # for debugging
  observe({
    print(df())
    # print(nms())
    # print(map(names(input), ~input[[.x]]))
  })


  observeEvent(df(), {
    nms(map(df(), names))
  })

  output$filters <- renderUI({
    req(df())
    inpts <- tagList(
      numericInput("STUDYID", "STUDYID", value = NA),
      textInput("DOMAIN", "DOMAIN", value = ""),
      numericInput("VALUE", "VALUE", value = NA)
    )
  })

  output$tables <- renderUI({
    req(df())
    map(1:length(df()), ~ tableOutput(str_c("table", .x)))
  })

  observeEvent(c(input$STUDYID, input$DOMAIN, input$VALUE), {
    df <- df()
    # df contains multiple dataframes so we need to loop through each of them to create the render functions
    walk(1:length(df), ~ {
      output[[str_c("table", .x)]] <<- renderTable({
        cur_df <- df[[.x]]
        nms <- nms()[[.x]]
        nms <- map(suffixes, ~ str_subset(nms, .)) # to order the correct column names with the required input. Warning, if more than one name matches the suffix is not tested
        # first we look if the input is character type and force a NA value on it, if it's not we just look for NA.
        # If the input is not NA (meaning that is has a value inserted by the user), then filter the table by that value.
        walk2(nms, suffixes, ~ {
          if (class(input[[.y]]) == "character") {
            if (input[[.y]] == "") {
              input_value <- NA
            } else {
              input_value <- input[[.y]]
            }
          } else {
            input_value <- input[[.y]]
          } # empty textInput's show has an empty string value instead of NA
          print(input_value)
          if (!is.na(input_value)) {
            cur_df <<- cur_df %>% filter(.data[[.x]] == input[[.y]])
          }
        })
        cur_df
      })
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: yes it reads multiple xpt files now. Could you also assist me with my second question? It should pull all the matching rows from those several xpt files where I need to filter any column values.

Comment: @KevinTracey Can you elaborate a bit more? where does the match come from? What do you mean by any column values? Do the multiple xpt files have the same structure? Can you provide actual data to work with? Thanks.

Comment: I have updated my original post to include xpt1 and xpt2. I've also highlighted that when I filter the column values with 1.9(for example), my expected output should be as  '3           CR        1.9'.  Note: I should be able to filter based on any column value.

Comment: @KevinTracey I added an app with a filter that let's the user select ,STUDYID DOMAIN and a value that is searched within the possible VALUE column. Did you want the user to first selec which uploaded file to filter and then show the possible columns?

Comment: Thank you, and yes I want to filter with values associated with multiple xpt files.

Comment: Can you help me with this.?

Comment: The code above (Edit: The app with filter) currently shows Table after we select its values of the columns after the xpt upload. Could you perhaps assist me in figuring out how to display this table as soon as the user uploads the xpt files? Also, how should I construct a single view that shows the table of several xpt files, so that the rows from numerous xpt files may be seen in a single.

Comment: The easiest way to show the table as soon the upload happens is to select everything in the filters from the start. Regarding the second question, we can combine the different files (assuming the structure of STUDYID, DOMAIN and *_VALUE) with `pivot_longer`, please see edit2.

Comment: Yes, everything works as intended; but, one final thing I am expecting is, whenever I pick multiple.xpt files, it displays both.xpt files side by side; however, I want it to display both.xpt files one by one in the bottom so that when I filter with any values, the corresponding rows are displayed one by one.

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand. Do you want to show one table for each .xpt? And to be able to filter each of that tables? Maybe using `DT` package can be better than creating filters for all of that tables.

Comment: I would like to upload numerous xpt files and filter them at once. In EDIT 2, the tables are currently displayed side by side, but I would like them to be displayed in the bottoms, for example, xpt1 at the top and xpt2 at the bottom, so that when I filter with values, the associated rows are displayed one by one. I hope this information is useful.

Comment: It currently works as a column bind in the code Edit 2. I would like to do the same with row bind.

Comment: You mean this format? `tibble::tribble(
    ~STUDYID, ~DOMAIN,  ~CR,  ~CM,
           1,    "CR",  1.5,   NA,
           2,    "CR",  1.5,   NA,
           3,    "CR",  1.5,  1.9,
           1,    "CM",   NA,  1.5,
           2,    "CM",   NA,  1.8
    )
`

Comment: Yes, it currently joins tables side by side, but I would like to join at the bottoms

Comment: I edited  to display that format. Does the NA's bother you in the combined table?

Comment: I can see it still displays the combined tables side by side with NA. Could you perhaps bring these bottom by bottom?. Yes, it could be better if it does not display NA values too

Comment: Perhaps render two tables, one for xpt1 and the other for xpt2 etc.  And leave the three filters, are the three pickerInputs ok?

Comment: but in the future, I will have to upload multiple xpt files and filter

Comment: Yes, upload multiple xpt files and have one table for each of them.  At the moment we have two files with a similar structure. I am assuming three columns , two being the same and a third one that will contain xx_VALUE.

Comment: yes that works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240945/discussion-between-kevin-tracey-and-jpdugo17).

Comment: yes, it (Edit code) works great now. Thank you for the expected solution.