# How to I bring filters at the top of the datatable in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, rscript

Overview of this Shiny App:
This r shiny app takes multiple .xpt files and creates column-based filters on the left side of the panel (STUDYID, DOMAIN, VALUE, SEQ).
Instead of using the side panel, I'd like to move the column filters to the top of the datatable to match its columns.

Note: After reading my earlier article, this is the expanded question:[How can I display multiple.xpt files in R shiny and filter them based on their columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70508404/how-can-i-display-multiple-xpt-files-in-r-shiny-and-filter-them-based-on-their-c)

**Data:**

**xpt1:**

```
STUDYID   DOMAIN    CR_VALUE
1           CR        1.5
2           CR        1.5
3           CR        1.5
```

**xpt2**

```
STUDYID   DOMAIN    CM_VALUE
1           CM        1.5
2           CM        1.8
3           CR        1.9
```

**code**

```
library(shiny)
library(haven)
library(stringr)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
                multiple = TRUE,
                accept = c(
                  "text/csv",
                  "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                  ".csv", ".xpt"
                )
      ),
      tags$hr(),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
      uiOutput("files_available"),
      uiOutput("filters")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("tables")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  nms <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  suffixes <- c("STUDYID", "DOMAIN", "VALUE", "SEQ")
  
  df <- reactive({
    req(input$file1)
    input$file1$datapath %>%
      map(~ read_xpt(.x))
  })
  
  # for debugging
  observe({
    print(df())
    # print(nms())
    # print(map(names(input), ~input[[.x]]))
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(df(), {
    nms(map(df(), names))
  })
  
  output$filters <- renderUI({
    req(df())
    inpts <- tagList(
      numericInput("STUDYID", "STUDYID", value = NA),
      textInput("DOMAIN", "DOMAIN", value = ""),
      numericInput("VALUE", "VALUE", value = NA),
      numericInput("SEQ", "SEQ", value = NA)
    )
  })
  
  output$tables <- renderUI({
    req(df())
    map(1:length(df()), ~ tableOutput(str_c("table", .x)))
  })
  
  observeEvent(c(input$STUDYID, input$DOMAIN, input$VALUE, input$SEQ), {
    df <- df()
    # df contains multiple dataframes so we need to loop through each of them to create the render functions
    walk(1:length(df), ~ {
      output[[str_c("table", .x)]] <<- renderTable({
        cur_df <- df[[.x]]
        nms <- nms()[[.x]]
        nms <- map(suffixes, ~ str_subset(nms, .)) # to order the correct column names with the required input. Warning, if more than one name matches the suffix is not tested
        # first we look if the input is character type and force a NA value on it, if it's not we just look for NA.
        # If the input is not NA (meaning that is has a value inserted by the user), then filter the table by that value.
        walk2(nms, suffixes, ~ {
          if (class(input[[.y]]) == "character") {
            if (input[[.y]] == "") {
              input_value <- NA
            } else {
              input_value <- input[[.y]]
            }
          } else {
            input_value <- input[[.y]]
          } # empty textInput's show has an empty string value instead of NA
          print(input_value)
          if (!is.na(input_value)) {
            cur_df <<- cur_df %>% filter(.data[[.x]] == input[[.y]])
          }
        })
        cur_df
      })
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Since (on a cursory glance) it doesn't look like you're doing anything too custom with the filters, I'd recommend switching your table into a `DT::datatable()` which has a built-in option to add filtering for columns. Specifically, see section 2.8 in: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/

Comment: @Mikko Marttila, Could you help me where I have to implement this `DT::datatable()` in my existing code. As I tried with `output[[str_c("table", .x)]] <<- DT::renderDataTable({` which gives me empty table.

Comment: Sorry, but since I can't copy-and-paste the example in one go, I'd rather not dive too deep into it. However: Did you also replace `tableOutput` with `DT::dataTableOutput`?

Comment: @Mikko Marttila, Yes, I tried the same thing, however, it only gives me one search box for the entire table. I am looking for at the top of the data table, I'd want to add a search box for each column. An example from(in the Tab "View"): https://vnijs.shinyapps.io/radiant/?_ga=2.135467569.1457829373.1645704312-964945872.1611059144&SSUID=4b9ad9eb39